# What's wrong in this syntax? How should I make it work?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select name , room 
from class 
where room="R128" 
   or name in (select cname 
               from enrolled 
               group by cname 
               having count(*)>=5;
            );
```

Also this query seems that it will take more time as it is finding out whether each of its name is present among any of the cname as mentioned. Can you do any better?

Comment: IS this a quiz. _Oh lord I didnt revise_

Comment: Start by taking the `;` off after `>=5;`

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes around the string constant are suspicious but it should work.  The following probably won't fix the query, but you should qualify all column names and use aliases.  And, it is often better to use explicit `join` rather than `in` -- well, the more recent versions of MySQL have fixed this performance problem, but you can try:

```
select c.name, c.room 
from class c left join
     (select e.cname 
      from enrolled e
      group by e.cname 
      having count(*) >= 5
     ) ec
     on c.name = ec.cname
where c.room = 'R128' or ec.cname is not null
```

And for performance, you might want an index on `class(name, room)` and `enrolled(cname)`, you can write the query like this:

```
select c.name, c.room 
from class c 
where c.room = 'R128' or
      (select count(*) from enrolled e where e.cname = c.name) >= 5
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Also can you find what's wrong here?: select sname from student where snum in (select snum from enrolled;);

Comment: @StuperDuper . . . Questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Comment: Ok I'll take care from next time @Gordon